# How to compile/execute ROS with modified source code

Tags: ros, rosout, build-from-source, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon,

I am in the process of creating a custom version of rosout. I have successfully followed the tutorial to install ros from source, and have a modified version of the rosout.cpp file. I am not sure how to integrate this into ros's prebuilt compiling mechanism "catkin_make_isolated".

What I have:

- makefile(.ccp -> exe)
- rosout.cpp
- rosout.exe

What I need:

A way to permanently integrate the new rosout file into ros. I curretly have a workaround to test, but cannot figure out how to properly add my rosout file to roscore.

Is there a directory that I could just drop the rosout executable into? If I do that are there other variables that need to be set?

Thank you!

Edit: I can place the executable in `~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/rosout/` and everything works fine, but I am looking for the proper method of accomplishing this rather than a workaround. I am guessing there is a makefile/cmakefile but I cannot find the correct one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259129/how-to-compile/execute-ros-with-modified-source-code/) by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2017-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-12**:
You have `rosout.exe`? Are you using Windows?

**Comment by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) on 2017-04-12**:
No, ubuntu, I compiled rosout manually into a program file. This was a temporary solution for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out my problem, so I will update here for anyone who comes across this.

Since I was able to compile rosout.cpp into an executable, all I needed to do was replace the pre-existing rosout.exe with the version I modified and compliled. This file is located by default in `opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout`(non-source ros). I didn't realize I had access to the exectables in non-source versions of ros, with this information I was able to complete my build.

---

Originally posted by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) with karma: 67 on 2017-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spooner-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/29765/spooner-dev/) on 2017-04-28**:
A cleaner solution would be creating an overlay catkin workspace, building there core packages you need and sourcing its devel/setup.bash after the main distribution setup.bash